# Simple method for running JS code stored in Wasm module

Tags: javascript, browser, webassembly

From imported function ("Evaluator"), how do I evaluate strings that is stored in WASM memory? String tells to "Evaluator" what to do in browser.

Trivial answer is to import function that takes pointer to memory and calls `eval`

Trivial "Evaluator" implementation :

```
 Evaluator: function(ptr) {

    eval(UTF8ToString(ptr));
  },
```

It requires only 2 methods:

- `Evaluator()`
- `UTF8ToString()`

Is there any better method that doesn't use `eval`?

EDIT: "Evaluator" function should :

- be as thin as possible
- not use `eval`

String stored in Wasm module memory can be anything.

Comment: Are you asking how to call javascript from webassembly or are you asking how to call javascript from emscripten? The two things are not the same any more than assembly language vs C++. Your title and tags says one thing, your example suggests you want to ask a different question with a different title and different tags. Please fix one or other. If you're asking about emscripten then see the docs https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html

Comment: I ask for a minimalistic js code that can call other js methods, so i can import this code to WASM and invoke it with parameters such as `objptr`, `mehodptr`, `methodArgsPtr`. I want to put as much possible amount of code in wasm module, and use only bare minimal amount of non WASM js code required. I don't want to use emscripten because it adds too much of unecessary js code.

Comment: I get the impression you don't understand what webassembly is but if I'm wrong I'm sorry for mis-judging. [Here's an gist on how to call JavaScript from Web**Assembly**](https://gist.github.com/cure53/f4581cee76d2445d8bd91f03d4fa7d3b). Like I said I don't think you wanted webassembly though I think you wanted C++ which means emscripten. C++ has a runtime so emscripten adds it by default. I'm sure you can compile C++ in emscripten without any runtime support tho

Comment: If you want to know how to call JavaScript from C++ then ask that. If you really wanted to call JavaScript from WebAssembly then you need to write WebAssembly code which looks a lot like assembly language and nothing like C/C++

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is the answer you want but it is the answer to the question you asked. So if this is not the answer you wanted then **ask a new question**

Here's some WebAssembly in WebAssembly text format

```
(module
  (func $i (import "imports" "imported_func") (param i32))
  (func (export "exported_func")
    i32.const 42
    call $i
  )
)
```

- It imports a JavaScript function called "imported_func".
- It exports a wasm function called "exported_func".
- "exported_func" calls "imported_func" with 42

To use that it needs to be converted to web assembly binary format. I used [the `wat2wasm` tool](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt). It gave me this data

```
  0x00, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x02, 0x60,
  0x01, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x19, 0x01, 0x07, 0x69, 0x6d,
  0x70, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x74, 0x73, 0x0d, 0x69, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x74,
  0x65, 0x64, 0x5f, 0x66, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01,
  0x01, 0x07, 0x11, 0x01, 0x0d, 0x65, 0x78, 0x70, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x74, 0x65,
  0x64, 0x5f, 0x66, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0a, 0x08, 0x01, 0x06,
  0x00, 0x41, 0x2a, 0x10, 0x00, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x14, 0x04, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x6d,
  0x65, 0x01, 0x04, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x69, 0x02, 0x07, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00
```

To use it normally we'd store the binary version of that data then `fetch` it but to keep it simple I'll we'll just put it in the JavaScript directly, load it as a wasm module, pass it a function for "imported_func" then call it's "exported_func".

```js
async function main() {
  const wasmModule = new Uint8Array([
    0x00, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x02, 0x60,
    0x01, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x19, 0x01, 0x07, 0x69, 0x6d,
    0x70, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x74, 0x73, 0x0d, 0x69, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x74,
    0x65, 0x64, 0x5f, 0x66, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01,
    0x01, 0x07, 0x11, 0x01, 0x0d, 0x65, 0x78, 0x70, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x74, 0x65,
    0x64, 0x5f, 0x66, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0a, 0x08, 0x01, 0x06,
    0x00, 0x41, 0x2a, 0x10, 0x00, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x14, 0x04, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x6d,
    0x65, 0x01, 0x04, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x69, 0x02, 0x07, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,
  ]);

  const importObject = {
    imports: {
      imported_func: (v) => {
         console.log('js called from wasm:', v);
      },
    },
  };

  // create the webassembly
  const {instance} = await WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmModule, importObject);

  // get the web assembly function
  const { exported_func } = instance.exports;

  // call the wasm fucntion
  exported_func();
}
main();
```

That is WebAssembly. There are compilers that compile other languages that can generate WebAssembly. Emscripten takes C++ in and generates WebAssembly. Rust with some extra tooling can generate WebAssembly. How to call JavaScript from C++ via escripten or how to call JavaScript from Rust would be a different questions. Each of those languages and compilers define their own ways to call JavaScript. That's not how to call JavaScript from WebAssembly though, that' show to call JavaScript from those compilers. The answer above is how to call JavaScript from WebAssembly.

## Update

wasm has no knowledge of JavaScript. Nor even its host environment (could be Go, could be Python, etc ...). All it does is you can call functions in a wasm module and you can pass in functions to be called from the wasm module.

Normally if you wanted to have wasm call into the host language you'd write functions in the host language separately so they can be compiled (at load time or compile time)

For languages that can parse and compile at runtime you can embed strings in wasm and then call out to some function you write to take that string  and do something with it. One example

```
   function helperForWasm(str) {
     return eval(str);
   }
```

Now if you connect the code like the example above you'd get he result of evaluating `str`

Another example

```
   const idToJavaScript = {};
   function helperForPreEvaluatingJavaScript(id, js) {
     idToJavaScript[id] = eval(js);
   }
   function helperForCallingFuncById(id, arg1, arg2, arg3) {
     idToJavaScript[id](arg1, arg2, arg);
   }
```

Now you have 2 functions you can call from wasm. The first `eval`s a js string and assigns the result. If that string is something like

```
 '(function(v) { return v * 2; })'  // outer parens required
```

Then after being evaluated using the first function you could call it using the second

You could also do something like (pseudo code)

```
   function helperForLoadingJavaScriptFromString(js) {
     const blob = new Blob([js], {type: 'application/javascript'});
     const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     import(url).then((jsModule) => {
       // communicate jsModule entry points to wasm
     });
   }
```

Now call that with full source to JavaScript modules as strings. How you communicate the entries points into the module back to wasm is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the simple workflow of calling WASM module from JS. But the question was not how to call specific import from WASM module. Question was : How to run ANY  JS code that is stored in WASM memory. from imported function. Trivial answer is to import `emscripten_run_script` method and pass it memory pointer as argument. But i don't like it because it uses `eval`

Comment: You seem to not be paying attention to any of my comments or the answer itself. You keep asking questions about emscripten, not WebAssembly. WebAssembly has no way to embed JavaScript. emscripten does. It does exactly what I showed above. You type in C or C++, use some macros, etc and it builds WebAssembly and JavaScript separately and glues them together for you. So if you want to know how to use JavaScript in emscripten then **ASK A QUESTION ABOUT JAVASCRIPT IN EMSCRIPTEN**. The question you asked was JavaScript from WebAssembly which I've answered.

Comment: Maybe this is clearer. Imagine your Q was "How do I call Python from Assembly Lang" and in the details of your question you wrote C++ and tagged the question with just, "assembly". People would ask "Are you asking how to call Python from C++ or from Assembly Language". Those are 2 different questions with different answers. The question you asked was "How do I call JavaScript from WebAssembly" and you tagged with "WebAssembly". The question you want to ask is "How do I call JavaScript from emscripten" and you want to tag it with "emscripten" and "javascript"

Comment: You keep talking about `emscripten` , which i don't care about. I don't use `emscripten` or `c++` to make .wasm files. I use pure .wat files and convert it with `wat2wasm`.

Comment: you keep mentioning `emscripten_run_script` as a solution and you put that example in your question and a comment above. That's got nothing to do with wasm. Wasm doesn't have embedded JavaScript. emscripten has embedded javascipt. Emscripten separates that embedded javascript out, compiles the C/C++ to wasm, then generates a .js file with your embedded snippets and whatever other needed support. You end up with 2 files. a js file and a wasm file. The wasm file has no JS in it.

Comment: It is possible to  write JS code and store it as data in WASM module memory. Question is on running that code from browser, without using `eval`

Comment: No it is not possible to put JavaScript in a wasm module. In fact in the [entire spec](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/bikeshed/index.html) JavaScript is not even mentioned and in fact wasm is designed not to need JavaScript at all so it makes no sense you could embed JavaScript. It is possible to put strings in a wasm module and you can pass that string to eval. If you want actual JavaScript though that has to be in a separate file. You can then pass in references to functions defined in your separate JavaScript file into the wasm module (as shown in the answer above).

Comment: _"It is possible to put strings in a wasm module and you can pass that string to eval."_ That's what i need. Strings / Bytes / Whatever (stored in WASM memory) passed as a pointer to evaluating function. Evaluating function should be as thin as possible.

Comment: evaluating a string is eval. I'm still not sure what you're asking. All you get from wasm is a string. What you do with that string is up to you. Print it, eval it, put it in a blob and assign it to a script. It's just string, everything else is up to you. Maybe you want 2 strings, an id, and some JS. You pass all the strings and ids to JS, have JS eval every string and map the result to an id. Then you make another func that calls the previously evaled functions by id. Of course you still need JS to do that so might as well do what emscripten does and put the JS in a separate file.

Comment: Added some more examples of things you can do with strings passed from wasm. Maybe one of those is closer to what you were looking for?

Comment: Yep, that's closer to what i want. I can use Blob instead of eval. But I will probably just use eval then if the Blob is the only solution.  Rationale for doing this : I want to fully control browser from wasm module, using only bare minimal html/js for instantiating and running wasm.  Thanks anyway, if you have more ideas i would like to know them.